# sliding a fullscreen div down from screen top and loading slider into it

Tags: jquery, slider, webkit-transform

Hi I have a fullscreen slider I'm using, RoyalSlider.  I have a page with some images on it, what I'm trying to make happen is when you click the fullscreen button a fullscreen div slides down from the top covering the whole page and the slider gets loaded into that div through Jquery.

Here's how I was trying to accomplished this.  I had a div which I made two classes for:

```
.fullscreen_hide{
-webkit-transition-property: all; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s; 
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
width:100%;
height:0%;
background:#141414;
position:aboslute;
z-index:50000000;
}
.fullscreen_show{
-webkit-transition-property: all; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s; 
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#141414;
position:aboslute;
z-index:50000000;
}
```

I was swapping the classes and wanting the webkit transitions to do the animating, although this didn't work at all.  For some reason it doesn't slide down from the top and cover the whole page, it just kind of scrolls the page up to the top where the div has moved down about one screen height, but doesn't cover the whole page.

http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index_current_alt.html  if you go there and scroll to the thumbs, right above the box titled "a little more info" you can click the fullscreen button next to the thumbs and watch it fail live.  So that's the first thing I need help with.

The second part loading the slider I haven't tried yet because the first part failed, but I was just going to load the slider from this html doc http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html  into that div that slides down using this jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#color_launch").click(function() {
    $('#fullscreen')
       .html('<img src="http://www.klossal.com/loader.gif" style="padding-   
bottom:1000px;"/>')
       .load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
});
});
</script>
```

I think this will work because I have this set up on another part of my site, and it works, but I haven't tried, the only thing I could think that would go wrong is it would load before teh animation finished which is fine as long as it stays in that animating container and doesn't automatically go fullscreen.  The other problem I was actually having with this method of loading was controlling where the loading.gif shows up, any way to control that, ideally make it center of the loading area?

Lot of stuff there, but I think it's close to working?  Any help on this would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jq.animate` instead of having the full screen class, with animate you can give all those css options and have more cool effects.